# How to trigger the onsubmit event programmatically in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to programmatically call the onsubmit event of a form on click of a div element. I do not want to actually submit the form. I just want to call the onSubmit event. How do I achieve this?

```
    <form onSubmit={(event)=> {event.preventDefault();this.submitFunction()}>
 <ButtonWithIcon onClick={this.onClick} type="submit">
 </div>
 </form>

onClick=()=> { //need to call the call the onsubmit event }
```

ButtonWithIcon is a custom component that has the  as well as icon. So clicking on icon will not submit the form. On clicking of icon, I need

```
{(event)=> {event.preventDefault();this.submitFunction()} to execute
```

Comment: Can you post your solution? Even if it is not working? We won't code for you here ...

Comment: `<div onClick={this.yourOnSubmitFunction} />`

Comment: but you can do event.preventDefault() in onSubmit, then you can call any function you want, or get the event of onSubmit to do something? onSubmit=(e) => {e.preventDefault; console.log(e)}